# Configuring cucumber-guice

Tags: java, guice, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to use DI in my step definitions. I have a module,

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
    private final static MyInterface INSTANCE = new MyInterfaceImpl();

    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(MyInterface.class).toInstance(INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

and want to inject this instance in the constructor of the step definitions.

```
public class MyStepDefs
{
    private final MyInterface instance;

    @Inject
    public MyStepDefs(MyInterface instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance
    }
}
```

I think I need to configure the GuiceFactory using a cucumber-guice.properties file but I don't really know what this is? At the moment the error I get is,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Singleton
    at cucumber.runtime.java.guice.GuiceFactory$CucumberModule.configure(GuiceFactory.java:86)
```

Also should I be using a Provider for constructor injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MyModule` and `MyStepDefs` classes were fine. The `NoClassDefFoundError` was caused  by not having latest version of Guice added as a dependency. I added this,

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to my `POM.xml`.

The `cucumber-guice.properties` file goes in the `src/main/resources` folder. This file is read by the `GuiceFactory` class and should contain a property for the Guice module you want to use. EG..

`guiceModule=com.felix.cucumber.MyModule`

Answer (score 5):

As of cucumber-guice v1.2.4 this has changed slightly. Firstly the configuration file has changed its name, and it is now `cucumber.properties`.

Secondly, now in addition to building the module, you have to build a class which extends `cucumber.runtime.java.guice.InjectorSource` and set that as the value of `guice.injector-source` in the properties file. So in addition to the two classes you've already created you'd have to create a third:

```
public class MyInjectorSource implements InjectorSource {

       @Override
       public Injector getInjector() {
            return Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, CucumberModules.createScenarioModule(), new MyModule());
       }
}
```

then in `cucumber.properties` set guice.injector-source to the fully qualified name of this new class. `cucumber.properties` should, as before, be in `src/main/resources` (or `src/test/resources` depending on your requirements).

Naturally you still need the dependency in your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: In my case I just used `cucumber.properties` and set 
`guice.injector-source=com.xxx.yyy.inject.MyInjectorSource` inside `src/test/resources`

Comment: Yeah sorry - I accidentally wrote 'guice.properties' in the 2nd half of my answer. I've corrected it now.

Comment: `CucumberModules.SCENARIO` is now deprecated, use `CucumberModules.createScenarioModule()` instead