# cucumber-guice - using the injector

Tags: java, guice, cucumber-jvm

I am new to cucumber-jvm (and am returning to Java from a cucumber, Ruby background of a couple of years)

Using cucumber-guice I have successfully bound my dependencies and loaded my properties in a `CucumberModule`, and as such the `@Inject` annotation is triggering as expected.

So onto my question, in the provided `GuiceFactory` I can see the following code:

```
public <T> T More ...getInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
    return injector.getInstance(clazz);
}
```

So I should be able to to do a

```
XXXX.getInstance(myService.class);
```

But what is xxxx?

As far as I can tell `GuiceFactory` is loaded by cucumber-guice on running the tests but I have no idea what then holds the reference to it. Or am I looking at this the completely wrong way.

Comment: Never tried Cucumber-Guice, but now I certainly will. A bit of DI with the features would be very helpful. Anyway, have you tried simply injecting the `GuiceFactory` or the `Injector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not create instances by hand. The Factory uses guice to create all your Step-instances.

Whenever you used "@Inject" in your Step-class, guice will take care of the injection automatically without you interfering with the injector. 
You can configure the injection by providing FQN of the modules you wont to load in a cucumber-guice.properties file.

Useful links:

- [Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404434/configuring-cucumber-guice)
- [Sample on github](https://github.com/cucumber/cuke4duke/wiki/Guice)

Comment: Great thanks - I think my thinking was wrong on this. I will try it out and update

Comment: Thanks - I have been pointed in the right direction, I was going to update the question with why I was trying to do something different but realised what I was trying to do was daft (In the constructor of one object I was trying to go a getinstance basically replacing a new myService) when Iall i needed to do was @Inject!. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help ... when it comes to (C)DI, my favorite rule is: never use "new" :-)